# Prevent Google Admob Serving Limits

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I am new to AdMob. recently 4 months ago I placed some ads on my 2 apps by using Admob but unfortunately, I got a message about the serving limits of ads that were placed by AdMob to my AdMob account 2 times this happen. I want to know how to prevent these limits **is there any code that after 2 continuous clicks from the same user ads will disappear for some time for that particular user. so that it will be helpful to prevent the serving limits**?

Answer (score 0):

Hey the problem is source of traffic. Check your Analytics. Google AdMob works well with Organic traffic. Amy traffic apart from that can create a problem.

Ad serving limits: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9493252

Comment: But I Want to Know How We Prevent that like is there any code which helps me to prevent this type of problem... for eg. if someone clicks on my ads intentionally then after two clicks on my ads in a day it automatically disables those ads for that particular user.

Comment: There is no way you can add any code or so. You need to keep an eye on analytics and take action on any suspicious IP you think.

But if you think that someday did invalid clicks on your app then you can even report to Google Admob through this form.

https://support.google.com/admob/contact/invalid_activity

Answer (score 0):

But I Want to Know How We Prevent that like is there any code which helps me to prevent this type of problem...
for eg. if someone clicks on my ads intentionally then after two clicks on my ads in a day it automatically disables those ads for that particular user.